# Html5 audio on Chromecast - SSL

Tags: ssl, html5-audio, chromecast, subsonic, google-cast

Playing around with Html5 audio element on Chromecast with the source pointing to my instance of a Subsonic music server. You can set the music server to serve over http or https. If https, the audio element won't play. I've read a whole bunch on certificates etc but still not getting to a solution. The MediaPlayer in an Android app handles this fine (without any certificate) but on Chromecast with the Html5 audio element it doesn't work. Need some direction...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not gonna like this answer, but Chromecast simply won't support self-signed certs. It is built into the Chromium security model. IF you can get a cert side-loaded into the cert store, it would work (Android and Fire Tablet and TV can do this), it might help, but Chromecast (and FireStick) can't do that.

Comment: Thanks - figured as much. I'm trying a different approach that might work if I can figure out streams...  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42625370/nanohttpd-convert-https-stream-to-http